# Mule Queued-Asynchronous Flow Queue vs. VM Queue

Tags: mule, message-queue

While studying and using Mule, I couldn't figure out if there's a difference between a [queued-asynchronous flow queue](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/35X/Flow+Processing+Strategies#FlowProcessingStrategies-TheQueued-AsynchronousFlowProcessingStrategy) and a [VM queue](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/35X/VM+Transport+Reference).

My question is, are they the same queues (just with different names along the documentation) or different ones?

In a concrete example:

```xml
<flow name="fooFlow" processingStrategy="queued-asynchronous">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="foo" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
    <component class="com.foo.FooComponent"/>
</flow>
```

Does the VM inbound-endpoint receives messages from one queue, and the flow has another queue to receive the messages from the inbound-endpoint? Or are they the same SEDA queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two very different concepts, one is based on the way a flow is processed and the other is a lightweight queuing mechanism. VM is a transport and it has persistent queuing capabilities as well as transactions.

Please see (the last link to understand the flow execution model):

- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Flow+Processing+Strategies
- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/VM+Transport+Reference
- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance

Comment: I also read that documentation (I linked them in my question). So both are implementations of a SEDA queue? And both can be combined?

Comment: As I said, completely different things. You can connect two flows with the VM transport, however the queued-asynchronous processing strategy only influences directly (and visibly) on the performance of the flow execution.

Answer (score 0):

To add some details on the specific example you showed.

You do not need to specify the processing-strategy explicitly, Mule chooses the default processing strategy based on the exchange-pattern of the inbound endpoint. So as you have a non transactions one-way endpoint the processing strategy is queued-asynchronous.

[image]

> Does the VM inbound-endpoint receives messages from one queue, and the
>   flow has another queue to receive the messages from the
>   inbound-endpoint? Or are they the same SEDA queue?

To recieve messages Mule will use the thread pool dedicated to the VM connector (receiver threads are tied to the transport). Once the message has been received it will be processed using a thread from the flow's thread pool. (Would be great if I could be validated or corrected :)

(Most of the information is from the links posted in the earlier answer)

Comment: I'm aware of the different processing strategies and how they are automatically applied. My question is specific to queued-async processing strategy, which applies to my example -- one-way inbound endpoint and non-transactional flow.

Comment: Message received using thread from transport and processed using thread from flow.